# Using getView().findViewById in fragment returns NullPointerException

Tags: android

It does give me warning but I've never used fragments so I'm not sure how to fix it. I get the error on the third line of the code where I'm trying to find the toolbar.

```
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact, container, false);

        Toolbar toolbar = getView().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        TextView textView = getView().findViewById(R.id.vive_unadeca);
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {//do stuff here} });

        LinearLayout mapsT = getView().findViewById(R.id.locationT);
        ImageView mapsI = getView().findViewById(R.id.location);

        mapsT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {//do stuff here} });

        mapsI.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {//do stuff here} });

        LinearLayout phoneT = getView().findViewById(R.id.phone_num);
        ImageView phoneI = getView().findViewById(R.id.phone_icon);

        phoneT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {//do stuff here} });

        phoneI.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {//do stuff here} });

        LinearLayout emailT = getView().findViewById(R.id.email);
        ImageView emailI = getView().findViewById(R.id.email_icon);

        emailT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {//do stuff here} });

        emailI.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {//do stuff here} });

        LinearLayout whatsappT = getView().findViewById(R.id.whatsapp_num);
        ImageView whatsappI = getView().findViewById(R.id.whatsapp_icon);

        whatsappT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {//do stuff here} });

        whatsappI.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){//do stuff here} });

        return view;
    }
```

In the clickListeners I call other methods that are underneath the onCreateView which just call the intents like open gmail, open whatsapp, open phone call, google maps and facebook.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `getView()` inside `onCreateView()`. By that time, the `view` is not set, since you're right then constructing it.

The call to `getView()` will return non-null *after* `onCreateView()` and before `onDestroyView()`.

Instead, just call `view.findViewById` in the `View` you have just inflated, which I assume is what you want.

```
LinearLayout mapsT = view.findViewById(R.id.locationT);
```